# How to vary color of table row border based on div that it's in

Tags: css

I have multiple divs on a page and within each there could be one or more tables.  I would like the top of each table to have a color bar across the top and I would like the color to be determined by the div that the table is in.  I want to be able to move the table from one div to another without modifying any markup for the table and have it render with the color bar dictated by the div that it's in.

I don't have access to alter the markup of the table (unless I use some jquery on the client).  I do have the ability to update the CSS used on the page and I do have the ability to add/remove a class at the div level.

```
<div id="Zone1" class="purple-zone">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td id="cell1" class="cell-plain">Some content</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="Zone2" class="orange-zone"></div>
<div id="Zone3" class="green-zone"></div>
```

Thinking maybe some CSS along these lines:

```
.orange-zone.cell-plain
{
    border-top: 4px solid #f25316; /* orange */
}
.purple-zone.cell-plain
{
    border-top: 4px solid #631d76; /* purple */
}
.green-zone.cell-plain
{
    border-top: 4px solid #00a121; /* green */
}
```

This does not work and I'm not sure how to combine a class at the DIV level to define the color and a class at the TD level to apply the top border with the appropriate color.  I sense that this is possible with CSS, but I have not found the combination that works.

I want the TD in the example above to have a purple bar along the top and I want to be able to move that TABLE to a different DIV without changing the table's markup in any way, and have it take on the new color defined at the DIV level.  Also, only the TD tags in the DIV with the class of cell-plain should have this color bar treatment and no others elsewhere in the DIV.

I hope this makes sense.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: No comment on how to apply the color since I don't know that style declaration, but your selector is wrong:

`.a.b` means match one element with both class a and class b;

`.a .b` (note the space) means match one element with class b that is the descendent of another element with class a;

Also note that the descendent selector is the worst performing selector in CSS
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selectors should be as follows:

```
.orange-zone .cell-plain {
    border-top: 4px solid #f25316; /* orange */
}
.purple-zone .cell-plain {
    border-top: 4px solid #631d76; /* purple */
}
.green-zone .cell-plain {
    border-top: 4px solid #00a121; /* green */
}
```

Note space between `.orange-zone` and `.cell-plain`. It means that `.cell-plain` is descendant of the `.orange-zone`, while `.orange-zone.cell-plain` would work for markup `<div id="Zone1" class="orange-zone cell-plain">`.

Comment: Thanks dfsq for the incredibly fast and helpful response - this is exactly what I needed.  Works perfectly.